# Issue with combining @ORM\ManyToOne annotation with @ORM\JoinColumn anntation on same variable

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

Okay to describe the question I've been attempting to make a join column using doctrine annotations in order to save the username of a user instead of the user_id. I thought to achieve that by using @ORM\JoinColumn and @ORM\ManyToOne annotation but sadly it didn't work and I can't find a suitable way of doing it.

```
 /**
 * @Gedmo\Blameable(on="create")
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=User::class)
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="username", referencedColumnName="Username", nullable=false)
 */
private $created_by;
```

As you can see I combine this logic together with the @Gedmo\Blameable annotation in order to automate user action tracking to see who created the record in the table.

So my question is does somebody have experience with this usecase and what did you do to resolve this problem. I think I'm on the right track but can't find anything that resolves this issue.

I'm also thinking that I found an error in the Symfony Doctrine code because it passes the persistent check. As you can see in the image EnttiyManager->flush is passed. Sorry in advance don't have the right to embed the image.

[Errror Screen Symfony](https://i.stack.imgur.com/825Sj.png)

Meaning that this code piece succcesfully goes through the persist and reaches the flush. Changed the url to google because of privacy concerns once again.

```
        $betaallink = new Betaallink();
        $betaallink->setDepartment($department);
        $betaallink->setOwnreference($data["referentie"]);
        $betaallink->setActive(true);
        
        $betaallink->setReturnUrl("https://google.nl");

        $entityManager->persist($betaallink);
        $entityManager->flush();
```

And this is the database table for "Betaallink" which means in english "Paymentlink" in order to show that this column indeed exists. Once again no right to embed.

[DB Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfs3h.png)

I normally would if this was a personal project include the User table but because of specific column names I can't share it because of privacy concerns.

Sorry in advance for grammar and other langauge faults, I normally don't type or speak fluent English

Comment: it's probably not the solution, but the referencedColumnName is probably not starting with a capital letter? (must be the database column name in the *user* table)

Comment: Jakumi thx for your reply. Sadly enough that isn’t the case because that entity was created by another team member and had two days ago the opposite problem because I always use lowercase.

Comment: that makes me sad ;o/ also, in symfony property names will be snake_cased when the related database field is determined. So calling the property `createdBy` will imply the db field being called `created_by`. fyi. doesn't change the problem at hand, though ... I hope you find a solution ;o/

Comment: I honestly think that you already had the correct answer by using the user_id. Is it *really* necessary to store the username instead of the user_id? I would suggest to keep using the user_id, because it is a relation to the user entity. Thus, when retrieving your entity, you could easily do $entity->getUser->getUsername to retrieve the username. Hopelijk kom je eruit :)

Comment: @user2403735 Dank je, ;) I was hoping it could be combined because at work we have multiple people looking at the database and they have not all coding experience sadly enough. But I think I will proceed with the Id's thanks for your time if I find a possible solution to this I will post the answer.